# Unity transform.up not rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm trying to create some basic game AI logic that has one player run and avoid the other. This works fine but as I've done that, I'm now looking for the defender (previously static) to chase the runner. I struggled for a long time for this but found transform.up was the magic I was looking for as it used a players Y (green axis) to move on and used the rotation.

On my 2d plane this worked fine with runner running up the page but my defender is running down and there lies my issue. I *expected* that transform.up would go down the page as I'd rotated the character 180 degrees on the Z. What I've found is that transform.up is still going up the page and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

To move the players I'm doing the following (within Update() ):

```
transform.Translate(transform.up * 15f * Time.deltaTime);
```

To try and debug the issue, I've added the following into Start():

```
// DEBUG: Show position indicators;
if (showPositionIndicators == true) {

    Dictionary<string, Vector3> posIndicators = new Dictionary<string, Vector3>();
    posIndicators.Add("Up", transform.up);
    posIndicators.Add("Rt", transform.right);
    posIndicators.Add("Dn", -transform.up);
    posIndicators.Add("Lt", -transform.right);
    posIndicators.Add("Fd", transform.forward);
    posIndicators.Add("Bk", -transform.forward);

    Vector3 scaleLocPos = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f);
    dbgPosInd = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Vector3> posIndicator in posIndicators) {

        GameObject t = Instantiate(prefabPosInd, transform);
    t.name = "Pos_" + posIndicator.Key;
        t.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Scale(posIndicator.Value, scaleLocPos);
        t.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = posIndicator.Key;
        dbgPosInd.Add(t);
    }
}
```

This seems to indicate that indeed transform.up is "behind" and the same as the runner. Am I missing something simple? Is this intended? How would I go about having both players move forward relative to their own rotation (ie both run towards the middle)

[[image: Two circles. Blue circle (bottom) with up going up the page. Yellow circle (top) has up also going up the page.[1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `transform.up` as a local-space vector in `t.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Scale(posIndicator.Value, scaleLocPos);`, but `transform.up` gives the transforms local up vector in *world-space*. It is like a shorthand for `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);`.

The local-space up vector of an object rotated 180 degrees is ***down*** in world-space. You got that part right. But when you use it as the ***localPosition*** of a rotated object, since the object is rotated, that local-space position is set *down*, and will be ***up*** in world-space again.

That is why the "UP" debug text is upside down, as it should, yet positioned world-space up. It's because in the object's local space, it's down.

Use a `Vector3.up` (and other directions) in your `t.transform.localPosition` assignment, because the reference is already refering to local-space position.

---

Since `transform.Translate()` uses *local-space* by default, the same issue happens. Your local-space up (when getting) is down (in world-space), but your local-space translation down is back up in world-space.

Use `transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 15f * Time.deltaTime)` **(recommended)**, or make the translation relative to world-space, `transform.Translate(transform.up * 15f * Time.deltaTime`**`, Space.World`**`);`

---

Another potential problem:

Assuming your characters have, or will have, physics elements to them, don't do the movement in update, nor with transform. Use `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()` on `FixedUpdate()`. There is a `Rigidbody2d.position`, but that would override other physics effects, and so `MovePosition()` is recommended.

Comment: That worked perfectly, annoyingly I did have Vector3.up (and co) but changed it for consistency after discovering transform.up. 
  
If I change the transform.Translate to Vector3.up it doesn't avoid the defender like it did with transform.up (it rotates using a Quaternion.RotateTowards:  
```  
transform.Translate(transform.up * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationAmount), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);```